# Some Roberta weights are not initializing from the checkpoint

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, roberta-language-model

I got this warning after loading Roberta model from the checkpoint
Loading the trained model this way

```py
model = RobertaModel.load_from_checkpoint(checkpoint_path=<path>)
model.freeze()
```

Warning

> Some weights of RobertaModel were not initialized from the model
> checkpoint at roberta-base and are newly initialized:
> ['roberta.pooler.dense.bias', 'roberta.pooler.dense.weight']
>
> You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able
> to use it for predictions and inference.

Comment: The state_dict you are loading doesn't contain weights for these parameters. Had the model you saved these parameters?

Comment: I am not even using these parameters exclusively anywhere in the code

Comment: In this case, you can just ignore the warning.